# Replacing Dictionary with function

Tags: c#

I'm making a game with character attributes, like strength, agility, etc. I have them all in a `<string, double>` dictionary. I need to implement "mods" to attributes from equipment, buffs, etc. I'd like to replace all instances of `"CurrentStats[Key]"` with a `function(string input)` of some sort, via Find/Replace. (I have HUNDREDS of references to it, I can't do that all by hand)

So basically, I'm looking for a way to write a function where I can somehow write

`Function("Strength") = 5;` for assignment

while still being able to use

`if(Function("Strength") == 5)` for fetching.

Is this possible?

Comment: so you want to replace all values which matches a following key ?

Comment: You're editing your source code, right?

Comment: Enigmativity, yes. Kunal, I need to be able to change some other variable to whatever is on the other side of the equal sign using that syntax.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [ref returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)

Comment: @Damien, I just googled it. Yes, I think that's exactly what I need. Thank you very much

Comment: You can do this with the regex replace that's built in in Visual Studio...

Comment: Hmmm, that would give me more flexibility for my replace. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has inbuilt regular expressions in its search and replace. You just need to enable the option when doing your replace.

You can probably just perform a global search and replace of something like `CurrentStats\[([^\]]+)\]` to `MyFunction($1)`.

Explanation: this searches for the literal string `CurrentStats[]`, with the content between the two brackets being a group (referenced in the replace as `$1`), indicated by having it surrounded by `(` and `)`, containing `[^\]]+`, or, "a character group of anything that's not the closing quote `]`, repeated one or more times".

Note that this won't work if the key itself could contains something like `myArray[i]` since then it'll obviously match the closing bracket of that. Regex isn't really good at doing matching brackets or tags.

Comment: This and using ref returns should have me sorted very quickly. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The locigcal approach would be to have a class for your character. You can use properties. Functions are usually called with arguments if you want to assign something, but properties can be assigned directly.

```
public class Character {
    private bool overpowered = false;
    private int _strength = 0;
    public int Strength
    {
        get { return this._strength; }
        set {
            if (value > 10) { overpowered = true; }
            this._strength = value;
        }
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Then to use the property simple access it via the object:

```
Character c = new Character();
c.Strength = 5;
if (c.Strength == 5) { /* ... */ }
```

Using a dictionary makes little sense here.

Comment: I'm using a dictionary because I need to be able to iterate and display all existing stats. I also initialize my characters using System.Reflection, where it reads from an enum to add stats to the dictionary. This is so that I can later extend and add new attributes easily

Comment: @JonBrant you can use a dictionary internally then and implement the IEnumerable interface. Have a nested class Stats as aggregate to the character.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ref returns are what I was after. I don't know how to mark this as answered. First post here. Thanks everyone

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, then :) . You'll be prompted in some days to select the answer that you like best (it can be your own). Please consider adding more details, like a code example, in your answer, so that people who experience the same kind of problem can use it.